# very slow search results - mysqli - php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just learning how to do this so please forgive my ignorance!

This page loads VERY slow and the search almost doesn't run on my iphone (sometimes timesout).

Here is my test site: http://webtestkit.com/1KaraokeDJ/index.php

```
$view=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where
                              Title like '%$data%' ||
                              Artist like '%$data%' ||
                              Disc like '%$data%' ||
                              Brand like '%$data%'
                              limit 50");
```

is there a better way to do this search?
There are 28,000+ records now, but it will be in the 100k range later.

here is the full code:

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $_SESSION['title']= $search;
    if(($_SESSION['title'])!="")
      { header("location:index.php"); }
    else
      { echo "<script> alert('Please enter something to search for') </script>"; }
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>1KaraokeDJ.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login">
      <form method="post">
        <p><img src="top.jpg" /></p>
        <p>
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['title'])) { ?>
            <input name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['title'];?>" class="search" />
          <?php } else { ?>
            <input name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" placeholder="Just type your text here and press enter - ex : Abba"  class="search" />
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <datalist id="searchkey">
          <?php
            $tile=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `1KaraokeDJ`");
            while($storetitle=mysqli_fetch_object($tile))
          { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $storetitle->title ?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </datalist>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="click" class="searchbutton" value="Karaoke Search"  /></p>
        <hr style="width:100%">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['title'])) {
          if(($_SESSION['title']!=""))
          {
            $data=$_SESSION['title'];
            $view=$db->query("select * from 1KaraokeDJ where
                              Title like '%$data%' ||
                              Artist like '%$data%' ||
                              Disc like '%$data%' ||
                              Brand like '%$data%'
                              limit 50");
            $check=mysqli_num_rows($view);
            if($check!="")
            { while($descri=mysqli_fetch_object($view)) { ?>
        <div class="reslt">
          <h3 id="results">
            <?php
              echo str_replace($data, '<span class="highlight">'.$data."</span>", $descri->Artist);
              echo " - ";
              echo str_replace($data, '<span class="highlight">'.$data."</span>", $descri->Title);
            ?>
          </h3>
          <p class="Description">
            <?php
              echo str_replace($data, '<span class="highlight">'.$data."</span>", $descri->Brand);
              echo " - ";
              echo str_replace($data, '<span class="highlight">'.$data."</span>", $descri->Disc);
              echo " - ";
              echo $descri->Track;
            ?>
          <p>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <p><?php echo $check ?> Results</p>
        <p class="highlight">Showing Up To 50 Results - Try Refining Your Search</p>
        <?php   } else { ?>
          <div class="reslt">
            <h3 id="results">Nothing Found!</h3>
            <p class="Description">Try Changing Your Search Terms<p><hr>
          </div>
        <?php } } } ?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given that you can't use indexing effectively on a LIKE search, you might want to consider alternatives such as FULL TEXT SEARCH, or search for exact matches (which can be index based)

Comment: I'm curious if its actually the query slowing things down. "almost doesn't run on my iphone" The client device would not affect the speed of the query in any way. Using EXPLAIN can help you find the choke points in your query.

Comment: its the use of like and no indexes for the columns, the device cant slow things down but it can "choke" the conection if it takes too long, so it can be a browser issue

Comment: turns out it was the caching of datalist that was slowing the client down. Once I removed the datalist (for autocomplete) it was very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <datalist id="searchkey">
          <?php
            $tile=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `1KaraokeDJ`");
            while($storetitle=mysqli_fetch_object($tile))
          { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $storetitle->title ?>">
          <?php } ?>
        </datalist>
```

for whatever reason, saving a datalist to the client browser is very slow!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is:
 Place full-text indexes on your columns. Use match instead of like to actually use said indexes

an example of match

```
WHERE MATCH(field1 , field2) AGAINST ('aaa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

manual for match

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: using match against in boolean: a search for *"*van*"* does not return records with "Evans" or "Caravan" but does return "Vandross"... using like: a search for "van" returns anything containing "van"

Comment: Although I did figure out what was slowing it down, I'm not sure the purpose of the code and why I would want to use the client side browser this way:
 '      <datalist id="searchkey">
          <?php 
            $tile=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `1KaraokeDJ`");
            while($storetitle=mysqli_fetch_object($tile))
          { ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $storetitle->title ?>">
          <?php }   ?>
        </datalist>'

Comment: you are not using client side code. You are using server side code to fetch rows from the database, and output them in a loop. The code pretty much boils down to: Get everything from the database. For each row, print the row for the client. Also a datalist object is usually linked to an input object (you probably have <input list="searchkey"> somewhere) to assume a form of autocomplete. (while typing it suggests from the list like a select would, and if you pick something it parses its text to the input)

Comment: meaning each time your page loads, your entire tables title column gets loaded inside datalist object, (should you get hundrends of thousands of rows in that table it will be too costly to open it up, so keep that in mind)

Comment: Also should i suggest "SELECT title FROM 1KaraokeDJ" instead? it will greattly help you. You should avoid getting more data from the database than needed

Comment: You are correct, it it an autocomplete function! However, since it loads each time the page loads, on my iphone it takes too much memory. In a desktop browser it works just fine. I've already learned a good bit from playing with this code - I've been able to modify it and figure out a bunch... I guess I'll add something to see if it's a mobile device and turn the autocomplete off on mobile devices.

Comment: Also, how do i make the match search inside words? ie search for "van" return Evans and Vandross

Comment: That is up to the browser implementation, html5 datalist is still scarcely documented and no javascript api regarding its functions is set. To achieve both your questions i would suggest an autocomplete library for now (with a quick look https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/ seems prommissing although i didnt test it)

Comment: Otherwise try with an ajax autocomplete function.
Finally, to get what type of device is connected (though a user that tries to hide wont sent you proper information regarding that part, it will work for most normal users) https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/